# How can I get jetpacks in GTA 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I saw people saying there are jetpacks in GTA 5, but how can you get them? Do they even exist in the game?

Answer (score 6):

There's no jetpack in GTA V.

I tried following the instructions in the youtube video, even though it was already proved to be fake by CVG (a channel on YouTube).  This person called Jimbothy did some video editing and just trolled to a lot of people.  HoldTheKnife is another video uploader who did the same kind of thing.  Both methods do not work.  Just follow the comments under the videos.  A lot of angry people.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

After a super quick google search I found the following video(**ATTENTION!!! Possible spoilers inside**):

What is basically says:

1. Get a fast car(*[Adder](http://gta.wikia.com/Adder)* is recommended)
2. Go to the prison
3. Jump over the fence into the prison
4. Stay alive for 48 real time minutes
5. Get a chopper with machine guns(like a *[Little Bird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD_Helicopters_MH-6_Little_Bird)*)
6. Go to the [IAA building](http://gta.wikia.com/IAA_Headquarters)
7. Find some transparent see-through windows
8. Shoot it
9. Jump out and parachute right into the window(be careful, you will lose lots of health)
10. Find a *jetpack* there
11. Try to use it(<kbd>Right</kbd> on a D-Pad)
12. It will disappear and say that it will now appear at *48 Woodstone Cress*
13. *48 Woodstone Cress* is located not far from *[Franklin's](http://gta.wikia.com/Franklin_Clinton)* house
14. Get there, enjoy your jetpack :)

P.S. I did not try(and will not) to get a jetpack in *GTA V*, so I do not know if this video is real or a good fake one
P.P.S. Assuming *GTA V* has an *M rating* and one if its' parts is *Strong Language*, I did not add any warning about bad language in the video

Comment: It's fake. There is no jetpack in GTA V although I suspect one will show up in DLC.